# How to preserve buffer and window location (without manual save) between iTerm sessions?

Tags: macos, iterm, iterm2

How does one set iTerm to keep the buffer history (like Terminal.app's behavior) on OS X between quitting the app?

Also, it seems to reset Window Arrangement between sessions without manually saving it.  Can I set this so that it remembers these window positions without having to save them each time I move the window around?  This is kind of a hassle when using something like Flexiglass where I change things semi frequently.